# BusyIndicator is not working in silverlight MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, silverlight-5.0

Hi all,
                            i need to block the screen using busyindicator. when i click the view (Sample.xaml) the event was written in (Sample.xaml.cs) that leads to execute the code that was written in a separate class named (Sample.cs). So in the separate class file i have the implementation of busyindicator. but it doesn't work.

**Sample.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="Pool.View.CadViewer"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>
        <toolkit:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
        <Grid x:Name="CadLayoutRoot"  MouseLeftButtonUp="CadLayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseRightButtonDown="CadLayoutRoot_MouseRightButtonDown" MouseRightButtonUp="CadLayoutRoot_MouseRightButtonUp" MouseLeftButtonDown="CadLayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="CadLayoutRoot_MouseMove" MouseWheel="CadLayoutRoot_MouseWheel" LostMouseCapture="CadLayoutRoot_LostMouseCapture" >
        </Grid>
        </toolkit:BusyIndicator>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

**Sample.xaml.cs:**

```
private void CadLayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateViewAndViewModel();
}

private void UpdateViewAndViewModel()
{
    Sample bfmobj = new BFM(View.CadViewer.radius2, View.CadViewer.model.Blocks,
                    View.CadViewer.Step, View.CadViewer.StepType, View.CadViewer.StepPosition);
}
```

**Sample.cs:**

```
 public class Sample: ViewModelBase
 {
    public BFM(bool radius, DxfBlockCollection block, string step, string steptype, string stepposition)
    {
        this.Radius = radius;
        this.Block = block;
        this.Step = step;
        this.StepType = steptype;
        this.StepPosition = stepposition;

        GetBFMPart();

    }     
    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy
    {
       get { return _isBusy; }
       set
       {
          if (_isBusy != value)
          {
             _isBusy = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy");

          }
        }
     }
     public void GetBFMPart()
     {
        IsBusy = true;
     //code sample
        IsBusy = false;
     }
}
```

In the Function GetBFMPart i had the code to retrieve the data. So i need to block the Screen till the the data to be retrieved. How to do that? Please Help me to fix this issue..

Comment: where do you execute the method `GetBFMPart`?

Comment: Is the DataContext set corretly of view Pool.View.CadViewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for a start, you're creating your `Sample` object but not setting it as the `DataContext` for your view. Either modify the existing `ViewModel`/`DataContext` or replace it with the new `Sample` object you've created.

```
private void UpdateViewAndViewModel()
{
    Sample bfmobj = new BFM(View.CadViewer.radius2, View.CadViewer.model.Blocks,
                    View.CadViewer.Step, View.CadViewer.StepType, View.CadViewer.StepPosition);

    this.DataContext = bfmobj;
}
```

However, I think you may also run into issues to do with threading, but I'm not very familiar with Silverlight.

In standard WPF, the framework is waiting for your function to complete before it can update the UI, as your function is running on the UI thread. And since your function effectively doesn't change the value of that bool (it does, but because nothing else can execute before it's finished, the value remains unchanged), the UI stays the same.

You need to run your code that "does the work" on a separate thread, the easiest way to do this is to use a task:

```
public void GetBFMPart()
{
    IsBusy = true;

    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate
    {
        // do your work here then set IsBusy = false
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        IsBusy = false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Two Way and UpdateSourceTrigger to work

```
        <toolkit:BusyIndicator HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           BusyContent="{Binding BusyMessage,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           IsBusy="{Binding UserControlIsBusy,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       d:IsHidden="True" />
```